# Why httpd container stop working on restart of system?

Tags: apache, docker, docker-for-windows

On a fresh installation of httpd and PHP images and container get to create and work fine. But on restart of my system, httpd stop working. It's not able to find the docroot folder. So is there any setting we need to do for same.

Throw error:

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/docroot/] does not exist docker error
```

Comment: Use -d option (daemon mode) example: docker run -d hello-world

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Use a restart policy To configure the restart policy for a container,
>   use the --restart flag when using the docker run command. The value of
>   the --restart flag can be any of the following:

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Answer (score 0):

You have to start your container in daemon mode:

```
docker run -d hello-world
```